# Google Analytics for iOS, how to set domain?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to port this javascript version of GA to native iOS SDK

```
pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-1");
pageTracker._setDomainName(".test.org");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

I know how to set the UA account and how to report a pageView, but how do I set the domain name ?

```
 [[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-XXXXXXX-1"
                                    dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec
                                          delegate:nil];


  if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/"
                               withError:&error]) { // Handle error here  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the domain?  I've been using google analytics without the explicit need to do this for some time.

Comment: truthfully, I dont know, I got this javascript code from a 3rd party which is said to work right, and I am trying to port it to native. if I don't set the domain, how will it know which is it ? why is it needed in javascript and not with native code ?

Comment: its nots needed. the UA code is all you need to add. it will work fine.

Comment: thanks, just for my peace of mind, can you explain why google choose to include it in the javascript API and not in the iOS one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just following up from my comments.  You don't need domain in the Google Analytics native code tracker for iOS.  It's used on the web so you can track traffic at a more granular level on sites where multiple sub-domains might be used.  For example, if you have a generic "Products" web page, but the same Products page lives on dogs.mystore.com/products and cats.mystore.com/products, and you want to use the same tracker but differentiate the traffic between those two sites, you can leverage the domain variable in the Javascript API.  I can't think of a use case like this where it would be needed behind a native app.

Here's a reference for it related to the JavaScript API
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Bottom line, it's not needed.  :)